# Is there a way to get notified when my UIImageView.image property changes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to set an observer on a UIImageView.image property, so I can get notified of when the property has been changed? Perhaps with NSNotification? How would I go about doing this?

I have a large number of UIImageViews, so I'll need to know which one the change occurred on as well.

How do I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is called Key-Value Observing. Any object that is Key-Value Coding compliant can be observed, and this includes objects with properties. Have a read of [this programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177i) on how KVO works and how to use it. Here is a short example (disclaimer: it might not work)

```
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;

    // imageView is a UIImageView
    [imageView addObserver:self
                forKeyPath:@"image"
                   options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld
                   context:NULL];

    return self;
}

- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)path ofObject:(id) object change:(NSDictionary *) change context:(void *)context
{
    // this method is used for all observations, so you need to make sure
    // you are responding to the right one.
    if (object == imageView && [path isEqualToString:@"image"])
    {
        UIImage *newImage = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
        UIImage *oldImage = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey];

        // oldImage is the image *before* the property changed
        // newImage is the image *after* the property changed
    }
}
```

Comment: do not forget to remove observer in `-dealloc`, like this: `[imageView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"image"];`

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, use [KVO](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key-value_observing_in_swift). E.g.

```swift
imageView.observe(\.image, options: [.new]) { [weak self] (object, change) in
            // do something with image
        }
```

more discussions [How i detect changes image in a UIImageView in Swift iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67533596/how-i-detect-changes-image-in-a-uiimageview-in-swift-ios)