# detect if image of UIImage is changed (Xcode 6.1)

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, xcode6

I have a UIView that there is an empty UIImageView in it,and when the user picks a picture or select a pic from library,we fill this UIImageView and then save the view information.
I've filled this UIImageView initially by an image that shows "noImage", and I don't want to save this image.
So how can I understand that the image in UIImageView is "noImage" picture or the image that was selected by user?
(I don't need to be notified each time the image changed, I just want to know the image in UIImageView is "noImage" or sth else)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get notified when my UIImageView.image property changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508422/is-there-a-way-to-get-notified-when-my-uiimageview-image-property-changes)

Comment: thanks for your answer. no other solution exists for  the situation I explained?

Comment: Couldn't you just keep a BOOL flag called say userSelectedImage, default it to NO, set it to YES when user selects an image?

Comment: @Anna that is reasonable if you always have control over the image selection, yes.

Comment: Can't you just store the image as an instance variable and compare pointers?

Comment: You can use [KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).

Answer (score 0):

For loading "noImage" from bundle you can simply use:
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"noImage"];
This method looks in the system caches for an image object with the specified name and returns that object if it exists. If a matching image object is not already in the cache, this method locates and loads the image data from disk or asset catelog, and then returns the resulting object.
You can declare an instance var for storing a pointer of "noImage" object and
then simply compare it with UIImageView image property like this:

```
@interface MyClass ()
@property(strong, nonatomic) UIImage *noImage;
@end

@implementation MyClass
- (BOOL)isImageSelectedByUser {
    return (imageView.image != self.noImage);
}

- (UIImage *)noImage {
   return [UIImage imageNamed:@"noImage"];
}
@end
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this ..
consider your imageview is UIIMageView *imageviewfortest;
 and you are setting your image initaily like this 
Before user selecting...
imageviewfortest.image=[UIImage imagewith:@"no image.png"];
after user selecting from gallery
imageviewfortest.image=image from gallary
 We can check

if(imageviewfortest,image isEqualto:@"no image.png")
{
// user have not selected any image`enter code here`
}
else
{
// user selected image..