# How to detect if the image of UIImageView has changed

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have an app where the user can choose an image from the camera roll and than that image is loaded into an `UIImageView`. However, if the image is big there is a delay till the selected image actually appears in the `UIImageView` (Setting the image is not performed on the `main thread` so the UI does not get frozen). Until the image is set, I would like to show an activity indicator which notifies the user that the app did not freeze, its just loading the image. However I don't know how to detect when the image got set in the `UIImageView` to hide the activity indicator. I am guessing maybe KVO could help here, but I am not sure how to implement it properly.

Sorry for the noob question! :)

Comment: There is already an answer on how to KVO image property on UIImageView http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508422/is-there-a-way-to-get-notified-when-my-uiimageview-image-property-changes  Does this help?

Comment: Yep, I saw that but did not really understand how it works, neither did the tutorials on the net help. Thats why I decided to turn to you guys.

Comment: > There is another way to know that.
[click here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43389837/4328271)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe UIImageView image property using KVO. Add code to stop spinner in place of NSLog(@"imageReady");.

```
@implementation ViewController {
   __weak IBOutlet UIImageView *_imageView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   [_imageView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"image" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
  if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"image"]) {
     //Image ready
     //Stop loading spinner.
     NSLog(@"imageReady");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

If you're using swift you can also create `UIImageView` subclass and override `image` property to observe the values with `didSet`. Just remember to set the image of the superclass.

```
class ImageView: UIImageView {
    override var image: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            super.image = image
            println("Image Set")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's good to know but unfortunately I am not using Swift. :(

Answer (score 1):

1- create an `NSKeyValueObservation` property

2- initialize the property in viewDidLoad with `yourImageView.observe...`

3- set it so that it listens for `\.image` and set the options to `[.old, .new]`

4- remove the observer in deinit

```
@IBOutlet var yourImageView: UIImageView!

var observer: NSKeyValueObservation? // 1.

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    observer = nil // not necessary but still

    // 2.                            // 3.
    observer = yourImageView.observe(\.image, options: [.old, .new], changeHandler: { [weak self](imageView,_) in
            
        guard let img = imageView.image else { return }

        print("an image was set on your imageView, do something with the image", img)
    })
}

deinit {

    observer = nil // 4.
}
```