# How i detect changes image in a UIImageView in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am using `UIImageView` In my `UIViewController`. In my case, I want to do if my image view changes then let me know if it was changed or not.

Comment: Change means image in imageview changes? like you want to detect when image changes.

Comment: How is it going to change? and where do you need to detect that? Can you explain a bit about your goal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [KVO](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key-value_observing_in_swift).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    
    private var imageChangeObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        imageChangeObservation = imageView.observe(\.image, options: [.new]) { [weak self] (object, change) in
            print("Image changed")
        }
    }
}
```